# Invalid package version for a dependency

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I am using NuPack (https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuPack/) to create a Nuget automatically on build but when I go to upload my Nuget file, it gives me this error:
`Invalid package version for a dependency with id 'Newtonsoft.Json' in package 'Float.1.0.0': ''`.

1. What is the error telling me?
2. How do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with NuPack, but usually you'd have a a nuspec and need to specify the version of your dependency:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#dependencies

Look for your Newtonsoft.Json entry and provide a version following these guidelines:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue. I didn't have a .nuspec and I think NuPack just kind of assumed stuff in the absence of a .nuspec. I have removed NuPack and created a nuspec and I am now packaging manually and everything is good.